# Anglicized plural and zero plural

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

What is the difference between "anglicized plural" and "zero plural"? I found those terms used in http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/plural-of-status/ which says,

> What is the correct plural of status?
>
> - an anglicized plural *statuses*
> - the (zero) plural *status*. The second results from its being a Latin fourth declension noun … but also correlates with English use of the word as a mass noun, as in considering their relative status
>
> etc.

Comment: Anglicized plural: three ninjas. Zero plural: three ninja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Latin, certain nouns that ended in *-us* in nominative singular had the same form in nominative plural (so-called "4th declension" nouns). The term "zero plural" refers to the lack of change in the English word, or lack of an overt plural morpheme, going from singular **status** to plural **status**.

"Anglicized plural" refers to borrowing the word into the English language, and treating it as an English word, where the regular plural is formed by the morpheme *-s*/*-es*. According to this view, the singular **status** will change into **statuses** when pluralised.

Some other words that end in *-us* were "2nd declension" in Latin, and form plurals by replacing the singular *-us* with *-i* (like **alumnus** becoming **alumni** in plural). These would be neither "zero plurals" (as there is an observable change in form), nor would they be "Anglicized plurals" (as an Anglicized plural would have been *alumnuses*).