Negative one point(s)
We say

two pointS
one poinT
zero pointS

What about "negative one"? Point or Points?
Is the rule that one is the only singular number? If so, is negative one the same as one?
What, other than 'it sounds right when I hear it', is the basis of your answer?

There's also a bit of a helpful answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/q/207468/425655, or other results on this site from searching "zero plural."
